# ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.1 ignoring retry settings in TomEE

Tags: apache-tomee, activemq-artemis

I downloaded latest ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.1 (Windows 10, JDK 8) and can't get the `address-settings` to take affect. Reading the documentation (not much) on line I edited the `broker.xml` by adding:

```xml
<address-settings>
    <address-setting match="BETATESTQ">
        <dead-letter-address>BETATESTQ_DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>BETATESTQ_EXPIRY</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>30000</redelivery-delay>
        <redelivery-delay-multiplier>1.5</redelivery-delay-multiplier>         
        <redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>0.15</redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>
        <max-redelivery-delay>100000</max-redelivery-delay>
        <max-delivery-attempts>999</max-delivery-attempts>      
    </address-setting>   
</address-settings>

<addresses>
    <address name="BETATESTQ_DLQ">
        <anycast>
            <queue name="BETATESTQ_DLQ" />
        </anycast>
    </address>   
    <address name="BETATESTQ_EXPIRY">
        <anycast>
            <queue name="BETATESTQ_EXPIRY" />
        </anycast>
    </address>   
    <address name="BETATESTQ">
        <anycast>
            <queue name="BETATESTQ" />
        </anycast>
    </address>  
</addresses>
```

Everything else is default `broker.xml` when create a broker.

It seems to always use default values for `redelivery-delay`, `max-redelivery-delay`, `max-delivery-attempts`. It does read the dead letter and expiry values correctly. I can see the message getting retried in TomEE logs and shows up in Artemis console and moves to dead letter queue when done.

I am not passing in and delivery or retry data when put it on the queue initially (using bare minimal Java J2EE code).

How can I get it to not ignore `redelivery-delay`, `max-redelivery-delay`, `max-delivery-attempts`?

I connected to the queue with Apache TomEE (not using built-in ActiveMQ 5.x in TomEE but pointing it to ActiveMQ Artemis)

JMS listener:

```java
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.*;

@MessageDriven(name = "BETATESTQ", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "BETATESTQ"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") 
})
public class BetaTestQueueListener implements MessageListener, java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;     

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void onMessage(Message rcvMessage) {
        System.out.println("omMessage throw runtime exception");          
        throw new RuntimeException("trigger retry");
    }
}
```

12/20/19 - Working values I found for TomEE 8.0.0:

tomee.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>

    <Resource id="artemis" class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        ConnectorClassName=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory
        ConnectionParameters=host=127.0.0.1;port=61617;needClientAuth=false;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=../ssl/server_jks_keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=mypassword;trustStorePath=../ssl/client_jks_truststore.jks;trustStorePassword=mypassword;trustAll=true;verifyHost=false;wantClientAuth=false;needClientAuth=false;keyStoreProvider=JKS;trustSToreProvider=JKS
        UserName=admin
        Password=admin     
        JndiParams=java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.core.OpenEJBInitialContextFactory
    </Resource>

    <Resource id="MyJmsConnectionFactory"
              class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory"
              constructor="uri,username,password"
              type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
        uri=tcp://localhost:61617?needClientAuth=false;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=C:/apache-tomee-plus-8.0.0/ssl/server_jks_keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=mypassword;trustStorePath=C:/apache-tomee-plus-8.0.0/ssl/client_jks_truststore.jks;trustStorePassword=mypassword;trustAll=true;verifyHost=false;wantClientAuth=false;needClientAuth=false;keyStoreProvider=JKS;trustSToreProvider=JKS
        username=admin
        password=admin
        TransactionSupport=xa
        PoolMaxSize=20
        PoolMinSize=0   
    </Resource>     

    <Resource id="BETATESTQ_DLQ"
              class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.ActiveMQJMSClient"
              constructor="name"
              factory-name="createQueue"
              type="javax.jms.Queue">
        name=BETATESTQ_DLQ
    </Resource> 
    <Resource id="BETATESTQ"
              class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.ActiveMQJMSClient"
              constructor="name"
              factory-name="createQueue"
              type="javax.jms.Queue">
        name=BETATESTQ
    </Resource> 
    <Container id="mdb" type="MESSAGE">
        InstanceLimit = -1
        ResourceAdapter = artemis
        ActivationSpecClass = org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivationSpec
    </Container>
</tomee>
```

Java EE class to send JMS message:

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.jms.*;
import org.slf4j.*;

public final class JmsPublisherInstance2 implements java.io.Serializable { 
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsPublisherInstance2.class);

   public void send( String msg,
                     ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                     Queue queue ) throws Exception { 
      Session session = null;
      MessageProducer producer = null;
      TextMessage message = null;
      Connection connection = null;
      try {     
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();       
            connection.start();
            session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
            producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
            producer.send(message);
            session.commit();
      }  catch (Exception e) {
         session.rollback();
         LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
         throw e;
      }  finally {
          if (session!=null ) {
              session.close();
          }
          if (connection!=null ) {
              connection.close();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Java EE listener:

```java
import java.io.*;
import javax.annotation.*;
import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.jms.*;

@MessageDriven ( name = "BetaTESTQMDB" , activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue") ,
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination", propertyValue = "BetaTESTQ"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="maxSession", propertyValue = "5"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")
})

public class BetaTestQueueListener implements MessageListener, java.io.Serializable { 
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Resource(name="MyJmsConnectionFactory")
      private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

      @Resource
      private MessageDrivenContext mdbContext;

      @Resource(name = "BETATESTQ") 
      private javax.jms.Queue betaTestQ;      

      @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
      public void onMessage(Message rcvMessage) {
            try {
                jmsInstance.send("test message", connectionFactory, betaTestQ);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                mdbContext.setRollbackOnly();
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: What documentation did you read? The [ActiveMQ Artemis User Manual](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/) is fairly comprehensive at over 100,000 words long. The ["Message Redelivery and Undelivered Messages"](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/undelivered-messages.html) chapter covers these settings in a fair amount of detail.

Comment: There are also examples demonstrating [dead-letter](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/standard/dead-letter) and [delayed-redelivery](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/standard/delayed-redelivery) shipped with the broker which can easily be inspected, customized, and run (using `mvn verify`).

Comment: I added listener to above, I am using standard J2EE 1.7 java code for listener and publisher. I can see the message getting retried in tomee logs and shows up in artemis console and moves to dead letter queue when done, redelivery is triggered by throwing exception. Are messages that are put on queue using java and taken off with java not subject to retry values only openwire, core jms or Qpid?

Comment: First things first...The JMS spec says it is an application *error* for `onMessage` to throw an `Exception`. It goes onto to say that it is vendor specific what happens in this circumstance (i.e. not very portable). The JMS spec specifically states, "It is possible for a listener to throw a `RuntimeException`; however, this is considered a client programming error. Well-behaved listeners should catch such exceptions and attempt to divert messages causing them to some form of application-specific unprocessable message destination."

Comment: Given that you're in a Java EE context using container-managed transactions and `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)` I recommend that you `@Inject` a [`MessageDrivenContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/MessageDrivenContext.html) and invoke `setRollbackOnly()` in order to trigger redelivery. Using the `MessageDrivenContext` for transaction related operations has been the recommendation for most of the last two decades (starting when EJB 2.0 was released).

Comment: I don't really understand your question, "Are messages that are put on queue using java and taken off with java not subject to retry values only openwire, core jms or Qpid?" Java is a programming language and OpenWire, Core, and AMQP are wire protocols. They are apples and oranges. The question doesn't make sense. In any event, you haven't told me what protocol you're actually using. What have you configured in TomEE to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: I always use @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) and rollback but I am trying to evaluate product quickly to see if it would work. Its likely using existing tomee jars to connect which may include non artemis activemq jars. I was under the impression if I don't specify retry values putting items onto the queue that it would be taken from server settings but maybe that could be incorrect and random values are being added back? I am confident even with rollback same results here

Comment: It's worth noting that in both JMS generally and ActiveMQ in particular there is nothing which can be added to a message by its producer to dictate the behavior of redelivery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that you're using the OpenWire JMS client. This complicates matters because, as I understand it, the OpenWire JMS client implements redelivery in the client itself and those redelivery semantics are configured on the client side not the broker side. The broker doesn't have a chance to apply any kind of redelivery policy because the OpenWire client handles everything and doesn't inform the broker of the delivery failures. [This documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy) may help you configure redelivery for your OpenWire client.

That said, I recommend following [this tutorial](https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/post/apache-tomee-artemis). It demonstrates how to integrate TomEE and ActiveMQ Artemis without building/deploying the JCA RA. This will allow you to use the Core JMS client rather than the OpenWire JMS client.

If you want to go the RA route you can build the ActiveMQ Artemis JCA RA by running `mvn verify` from the `examples/features/sub-modules/artemis-ra-rar/` directory. The RA will be in the `target` directory named `artemis-rar-<version>.rar`.

Comment: any idea how to send username/password to  Core JMS using the method in that tutorial above, it only lists host/port and unlikely anyone want to leave server open to everyone with no authentication

Comment: Use `UserName` and `Password`. The [`org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQResourceAdapter`](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-ra/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/ra/ActiveMQResourceAdapter.java) has methods `setUserName()` and `setPassword()` which TomEE can use via reflection just like it does for the other parameters it's setting (e.g. `ConnectionParameters` and `JndiParams`).